# Implement an Assembly program in C and Python

Tags: python, c, assembly

I'm trying to understand a piece of Assembly program while there is no explanation for it:

```
;x is stored at 8(%ebp)

  movl 8(%ebp), %edx
  movl $0, %eax
  testl %edx, %edx
  je .L7

.L10:
  xorl %edx, %eax
  shrl %edx
  jne .L10

.L7:
  andl $1, %eax
```

I implement it in both C and Python:

```
unsigned fun_a(unsigned x) {
    int val = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        val = val ^ x;
        x = x >> 1;
    }
    return val && 1;
}

def fun_a(x):
    val = 0
    while x != 0:
        val = val ^ x
        x = x >> 1
    return val & 1
```

But they turn out to produce different result:

```
//C
fun_a(0) = 0
fun_a(1) = 1
fun_a(2) = 1
fun_a(3) = 1
fun_a(4) = 1
fun_a(5) = 1
fun_a(6) = 1
fun_a(7) = 1
fun_a(8) = 1
fun_a(9) = 1

#Python
fun_a(0) = 0
fun_a(1) = 1
fun_a(2) = 1
fun_a(3) = 0
fun_a(4) = 1
fun_a(5) = 0
fun_a(6) = 0
fun_a(7) = 1
fun_a(8) = 1
fun_a(9) = 0
```

What's wrong with my C/Python program?

Comment: last line is different.

Comment: Go to your nearest C manual and look up the difference between `&&` and `&`.

Comment: must use only one `&` in C code `&&` is used only for `if(statements) loops for/while(statements) and booleans like you did`

Comment: Agree,  though perhaps easier for search purposes are the terms 'logical'  and 'bitwise'

Comment: @lurker Ah, I see. May I ask, did my Python implementation correct?

Comment: Both your C and your Python skip the check for the function argument being 0.

Comment: @lurker I don't think another check is needed: `val` has been given 0 firstly and return value is `val & 1`.

Comment: @Rahn ah yes, that's true. I was just looking at the code literally, but you're right, it is a redundant check.

Comment: @lurker The check is present in the while loop condition.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin yes I am aware of that. I was taking the code rather literally at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c you return val && 1, which is a logical and. In python, return val & 1 is bitwise.